# subscribe not a function error, when a field of observable object is subscribed to

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
function Action() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable();
  self.action = ko.observable({});
  self.action.name = ko.observable();

  //This works fine
  self.name.subscribe(function(value) {
    // some logic
  });

  // This gives subscribe not function error  
  self.action.name.subscribe(function(value) {
    // some logic
  });
}
```

I can't understand this kind of behaviour. Can somebody help me with some explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Action` to this:

```
function Action() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable();
  self.action = ko.observable({
    name: ko.observable()
  });

  self.action().name.subscribe(function(value) {
    alert("changed");
  });

  self.name.subscribe(function(value) {
    // some logic
  });
}
```

`observable`s are functions. `self.action.name` is just name of the `observable` function. Not the inner `name` property you want to access. So, instead of accessing `action`'s name. Use `self.action().name`